# Load .xib View into Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

Currently I develop with a StoryBoard for the iPad. Additionally I add a Temp.xib file with a view. Now I want to add this View into a Scrollview on the Storyboard. This is my code:

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Temp" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
view.frame = CGRectMake(20, yPos, 728, 250);
[scrollView addSubview:view];
```

But I get this Error:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: this seems to be a storyboard configuration issue. Where is the launch arrow in Storyboard pointing to?

Comment: Currently I only have one ViewController in my StoryBoard so therefore this ViewControler is the Initial View Controller

Comment: You'd better show your App Delegate's codes, especially `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Holt sich den Pfad der SQLiteDatenbank
[self getSQLitePath];

// Setzt die definierte Farbe auf die Toolbar und Navigationbar
version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
isAtLeast6 = [version hasPrefix:@"6."];

return YES;
```

}